If we have a cube ABCDA'B'C'D' calculate the mesure of the angle between AC' and plane (A'BD).
question
If we have a cube ABCDA'B'C'D' calculate the mesure of the angle between AC' and plane (A'BD).
the drawing

As you can see i found the angle as being XYA where X is the proiectuon of A on A'O and Y is the intersection of AC' woth that plane.
I calculated AX as $l\sqrt{3}/3$
Now i dont know what to do forawrd!

$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = \Vert a \Vert \cdot \Vert b \Vert \cdot \cos{\phi}$

Your drawing is ugly : it wouldn't have taken you less than 5 minutes to use a ruler to draw the lines, or 5 minutes on Geogebra (if you are accustomed to it).

If you rotate the cube by 120° about $AC'$, you get the same cube as before but with permuted vertices. In particular $A'BD\to BA'D$ is transformed into itself, hence it is perpendicular to $AC'$.

The letters in the drawing are not legible (perhaps not written in latin characters, who knows).
So I'll make up my own system: Cartesian coordinates are $A=(0,0,0)$, $B=(1,0,0)$, $C=(1,1,0)$, $D=(0,1,0)$,
$A'=(0,0,1)$, $B'=(1,0,1)$, $C'=(1,1,1)$, $D'=(0,1,1)$.
The vector $AC'$ is $(1,1,1)$. The surface normal of the plane $A'BD$ is given by the cross product
of the line $A'B$ by the line $BD$. The line $A'B$ is the vector $(1,0,-1)$. The line $BD$ is the
vector $(-1,1,0)$. The cross product is $(1,1,1)$, not normalized to unity.
The surface normal is in the direction of $AC'$, so the angle 0 (if measured as an inclination
angle in the usual optics definition).
Of course there are solutions that differ by $90^\circ$ or $180^\circ$ or complements if you
measure angles differently.

Here's a "solution without words".

